# How to prevent user from removing disabled attribute and manually editing role?

Tags: html

So I am supposing the user has general knowledge of HTML.

I have this code:

```
<select name="role" id="role" disabled>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="Moderator" selected>Moderator</option>
    <option value="Subscriber">Subscriber</option>
</select>
```

This is an edited profile page for a user and a role is pre-selected from the server. If the user uses "inspect element" and removes the "disabled" attribute from the `select` element then he can change the role and save it.

How can I prevent user from changing the role?

Comment: You could try having the user roles set in a database such as mysql for each individual user. Then create a php script to retrieve those values and put them to use.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes i am saving it in database roles , its an update page where if user is smart and change the role, which he is not intended to.

Comment: Why don't you have the server check whether the user is allowed to check the role or not on the server ?

Comment: Maybe have a php script check what the current user roles are for that user if they are a subscriber then do not display the html code u listed above. You could use something like php echo to display the html

Comment: Do a server check and not showing select options for other user just displaying label for role is enough ?

Comment: @TimWilliams why are you so focused on PHP? There are plenty of other, much better options - and not to mention that this is a security site...

Answer (score 9):

Don't rely on the client.
That is, security on the client-side is not security.

Any security checks you do, or assumptions you make, on the client (aka HTML, javascript, etc) are irrelevant, and need to be performed on the server.
When the user submits the form, simply disallow any values the user is not authorized to.
And while you're at it, don't even provide the user with a select box to change the role... but don't assume that he didn't change it, even without a select! Simply do not accept any other values, and enforce this *on the server*.

Answer (score 6):

**This is client-side security. You are not able to fully secure your data on the client.**

This means, the user always has the possibility to "change" his role. I put this in quotes because he can't actually change the role, he just sends you his profile with another role. He could do this like you said, inspect the element and remove attributes. But he could also send a fake Http-request over Fiddler or similar.

What you need to do know is the **server-side** validation. You have to check, whether the user is allowed to change his role or not. Just handle the values you expect and drop the others.

**Don't trust data coming from a client!**